# Open Konsole window in KDE with Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, plasma5

I am used to using `` Ctrl+` `` to open Cmder in Windows. This key combination does not start a new Cmder process, but rather it maximizes or brings the already running one to the front and focuses on it.

In KDE Plasma, I can hit `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open a new Konsole window, but I don't have any shortcut that just opens the currently running Konsole window.

Is there any way to do this? I've looked at Keyboard shortcuts in Konsole, in the Global shortcuts, and even in the Panel.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

I'm running KDE Plasma 5.14.5.

Comment: Not an answer, but I use KDE and Terminator instead. I find this emulator more feature-rich, including a "popup" mode.

Answer (score 2):

I too use *wmctrl* but prefer to use something like:

```
wmctrl -xa Konsole || konsole
```

The idea being that if a window with Konsole in the WM_CLASS name exists (because of `-x`), bring it into focus. Otherwise, run the command `konsole`. `-x` may not always be needed but I leave it in to avoid issues with non-konsole windows having "konsole" in the filename.

I've assigned the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut to this command leaving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> as is.

If I still need to open an additional konsole window, I can do so using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or konsole's GUI interface.

Answer (score 1):

I was recommended a program that solves this problem for me: [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl).

```
wmctrl -a konsole
```

This performs exactly the function that I was looking for.